# mlflow.pytroch.load_model() can't load register model after the model class moved to another .py file

Tags: mlflow

when I moved the 'LstmModel' model class from '../lstm_ts.py' file to another package file, and use mlflow.pytorch.load_model or pyfunc to load the register model, I got a AttributeError like thiis below:
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'LstmModel' on <module 'mlops.tasks.lstm_ts' from '/home/mlops/tasks/lstm_ts.py'>
How to change the model package filepath or any other solution about the Exception to give a flexiblity, thank you!

Tracking information

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/zorro/project/pycharm/Fund/Index_Markup_Forecasting/test.py", line 22, in
loaded_model = mlflow.pyfunc.load_model(f'models:/{model_name}/{version}')._model_meta
File "/home/zorro/miniconda3/envs/ts/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mlflow/pyfunc/init.py", line 680, in load_model
model_impl = importlib.import_module(conf[MAIN])._load_pyfunc(data_path)
File "/home/zorro/miniconda3/envs/ts/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mlflow/pytorch/init.py", line 722, in _load_pyfunc
return _PyTorchWrapper(_load_model(path, **kwargs))
File "/home/zorro/miniconda3/envs/ts/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mlflow/pytorch/init.py", line 628, in _load_model
return torch.load(model_path, **kwargs)
File "/home/zorro/miniconda3/envs/ts/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 809, in load
return _load(opened_zipfile, map_location, pickle_module, **pickle_load_args)
File "/home/zorro/miniconda3/envs/ts/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 1172, in _load
result = unpickler.load()
File "/home/zorro/miniconda3/envs/ts/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 1165, in find_class
return super().find_class(mod_name, name)
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'LstmModel' on <module 'mlops.tasks.lstm_ts' from '/home/mlops/tasks/lstm_ts.py'>

How to modify the the model class package file location of register model in mlflow

Comment: I just recommended to import the new model class defined else where temporarily to the old file to load the model and save a new one, so it is solved.